# Prolog connection between 2 in a family tree

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog. I don't know how to get connection between two and get list of people in between.
This is the prolog code for the family tree [Elizabeth family tree](https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/3e1/3e1a5e7c-d7b1-4093-a4ba-3be68fba1ce9/php06LNhc.png)

```
 /* Facts */ I removed facts here so that it appears less code.
/* Facts -1 name(<short-name>, <full-name>) */
/* Facts -3 parent(<parent-short-name>, <child-short-name>) */
/* Facts -2 male(<short-name>) and female<short-name>) */
/* Facts -4 position(<short-name>, <rank>, <place>) */

/* Rules */
father(X,Y):- parent(X,Y),male(X).
 
mother(X,Y):- parent(X,Y),female(X).

sibling(X, Y):- parent(Z, X),parent(Z, Y), X \= Y.


descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
descendant(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), descendant(Z, Y).

firstcousin(X,Y) :-
     parent(X1,X),
     parent(Y1,Y),
     sibling(X1,Y1).

cousin(X,Y) :- father(Z,X), father(W,Y), sibling(W,Z),not(X=Y).
/*connection(X,Y,L) where L is a list of people in between X and Y.*/
connection(X,Y,L) :- /* code goes here */
```

> example: connection(isla, mia,L)should return L = [isla,peter , zara ,mia]
> And I don't know how lists work in prolog.

Thank You.

Comment: what did you try? Unrelated: The family tree might be outdated :-)

Comment: I know that is not your question, but don't you consider Harry and Zara cousins?

Comment: are you sure you don't wanna get [isla, peter, anne, zara, mia] ? In other words: who do you consider to be **directly** connected?

Comment: connection(isla, mia,L) here isla and mia are connected to as cousins so peter and zara are added to list and also peter and zara are in between people. I didn't get how to return a list of people in between.

Comment: you first need to specify what you exactly want. When are two persons considered to be **directly** connected, i.e. can appear **directly** after each other in a connection list?

Comment: Look, this is a simple graph-problem. Has been asked here many times. The first step towards an answer is a clear specification.